# How do i select multiple object Using Python Script?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to select Cube.001,Cube.002,Cube.003,Cube.004 at the same time.
trying this script

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube.001","Cube.002","Cube.003","Cube.004"].select_set(state=True)
```

But is not working. What should i do to select this four objects ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to *select all objects* at once, then use: [`bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=select_all#bpy.ops.object.select_all) (`select_all` *operator*). In case you want to only select a *subset* of objects you have to iterate through the list of scene objects (`bpy.context.scene.objects`) or through the list of objects in the blend-file:

**Blender 2.7x**

```
# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    # Check for given object names
    if o.name in ("Cube.026","Cube.027","Cube.028"):
        o.select = True
```

**Blender 2.8x**

```
# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    # Check for given object names
    if o.name in ("Cube.026","Cube.027","Cube.028"):
        o.select_set(True)
```

Comment: Write the code for me replacing the old one . I am finding it hard.

Comment: Below code is workinf fine but i want something like mine one ..

for o in ("Cube.026", "Cube.027","Cube.028","Cube.029","Cube.030","Cube.031"):
   obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(o)
   if obj: obj.select_set(True)

Comment: see edit above for code